# IntelliJ - Increase lambda indentation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, indentation

When writing a lambda function, IntelliJ 2016.1.3 will indent the code like so:

```
IntStream.of(1, 2).forEach(i -> {
     //Do some things
});
```

However, our code styles requires an additional level of indentation:

```
IntStream.of(1, 2).forEach(i -> {
        //Do some things
    });
```

I like auto formatting my code before a commit so I have to fix this manually.

I can't seem to find the correct settings. I have tried increasing the continuation indent and a few other seemingly applicable settings to no avail. The same goes for anonymous classes.

Comment: Your team's code styles hurts something in me. But there should be an option in the settings -> editor -> code style -> java somewhere.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat and it's hurting my builds! Unfortunatly it's out of my hands. And as I said, I did look through the code style settings but can't find anything relating to the indentation of lambdas